# How to check if few rows combined together in one table meet a certain criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not too much of an adept, when it comes to SQL and DB's, yet I am struggling with quite a serious (compared to my knowledge) problem:

I have a table with all the absences of all the employees, caused by a sick leaves with columns representing 'date_from', date_to' and the 'duration' of an absence. I need to select every employee that was on a sick leave for at least 30 consecutive days. The bit that I find problematic here, is that one person could be submit more than one sick leave document registered in the DB. It means that a person could be on a sick leave for 30 consecutive days, however that information is to be confirmed, when checking more than one record with particular 'employee_id'.

To illustrate it on example:

```
Employee_id | Name        | Date_from   | Date_to     | Duration
------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------
   00001    | John Newbie | 01-Apr-2018 | 25-Apr-2018 | 25 days
   00001    | John Newbie | 26-Apr-2018 | 03-May-2018 |  8 days
```

In this example, the asbecne would sum up to 33 days and this employee should be returned by the query, whereas should there be at least one day of a gap between those 2 records (for example the employee was present at work on 26th of April and absent starting 27th of April), this employee should not be in the report.

I have no idea how to start with that. I appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: You've got yourself a [gaps and islands problem](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/). That is not simple to solve.

Comment: You're going to need a stored procedure with a cursor. Query would group by employee id, sort by date_from and add 1 day to date_to for date_to_compare. Cursor would go thru each employee record seeing if date_from = last date_to_compare

Comment: @dbmitch Could you please elaborate more on that option? How do I fetch all the rows for a specific employee to operate on them in a loop?

Answer (score 3):

This is called a "gap-and-islands" problem.  It is made a bit more complicated by having start and end dates.

The idea is to determine where the islands start.  You can do this by taking a start that has no overlaps and then using a cumulative sum to identify the groups.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select employee_id, min(date_from) as date_from, max(date_to) as date_to
from (select a.*, sum(flag_start) as grp
      from (select a.*,
                   (case when exists (select 1
                                      from absences a2
                                      where a2.employee_id = a.employee_id and
                                            a2.date_from <= a.date_to and
                                            a2.date_to >= a.date_from
                                     )
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as flag_start
            from absences a
           ) a
     ) a
group by employee_id, grp
having max(date_to) >= date_add(day, 30, min(date_from));
```

Comment: Nice touch. Great bit of t-sql.

Comment: This is really impressive, even to that extend that I find it hard to get a grasp, what this query exactly does. I tried to use it bluntly on my prod DB, substituting only the table name and columns for the real ones, however SQL Developer was constantly throwing me a 'not a group by expression' error. Another question that popped in my head was, will this allow me to serve the case, where more than 2 consecutive sick leaves contributed to the limit of 30 days being exceeded (let's say 5 sick leaves in a row)?

Comment: @Przemek . . . I don't follow your comment.  Perhaps you should ask a new question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

`Lag` function that is available from SQL server 2012 is very useful in such cases

```
select
    Employee_id, Name, Date_from = min(Date_from), Date_to = max(Date_to), Duration = sum(Duration)
from (
    select
        Employee_id, Name, Date_from, Date_to, Duration
        , grp = sum(iif(datediff(dd, previous, Date_from) = 1, 0, 1)) over (partition by Employee_id order by Date_from)
    from (
        select 
            *, previous = lag(Date_to) over (partition by Employee_id order by Date_from)
        from myTable
    ) t
) t
group by Employee_id, Name, grp
having sum(Duration) >= 30
```